# C++ vim IDE. Things you'd need from it

Tags: c++, vim, ide

I was going to create the C++ IDE **Vim** extendable **plugin**. It is not a problem to make one which will satisfy my own needs.

This plugin was going to work with workspaces, projects and its dependencies.
This is for unix like system with **gcc** as c++ compiler.

So my question is what is the most important things you'd need from an IDE? Please take in account that this is Vim, where almost all, almost, is possible.

*Several questions:*
How often do you manage different workspaces with projects inside them and their relationships between them? What is the most annoying things in this process.
Is is necessary to recreate "project" from the Makefile?

Thanks.

*Reason to create this plugin:*

With a bunch of plugins and self written ones we can simulate most of things. It is ok when we work on a one big "infinitive" project.
Good when we already have a makefile or jam file. Bad when we have to create our owns, mostly by copy and paste existing.
All ctags and cscope related things have to know about list of a real project files. And we create such ones. This <project#get_list_of_files()> and many similar could be a good project api function to cooperate with an existing and the future plugins.
Cooperation with an existing makefiles can help to find out the list of the real project files and the executable name.
With plugin system inside the plugin there can be different project templates.

Above are some reasons why I will start the job. I'd like to hear your one.

Comment: Have you look at F.Mehner cvim package?
http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=213

Comment: I had. There is nothing project/workspace related, makefiles creation, is there?

Comment: @Mykola Golubyev Have you finished your project? I was looking for something like that, and I'd be glad to use your product :D

Comment: @MykolaGolubyev , is there anything I could use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- debugger
- source code navigation tools (now I am using http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1638 plugin and ctags)
- compile lib/project/one source file from ide
- navigation by files in project
- work with source control system
- easy acces to file changes history
- rename file/variable/method functions
- easy access to c++ help
- easy change project settings (Makefiles, jam, etc)
- fast autocomplette for paths/variables/methods/parameters
- smart identation for new scopes (also it will be good thing if developer will have posibility to setup identation rules)
- highlighting incorrect by code convenstion identation (tabs instead spaces, spaces after ";", spaces near "(" or ")", etc)
- reformating selected block by convenstion

Answer (score 12):

There are multiple problems. Most of them are already solved by independent and generic plugins.

### Regarding the definition of what is a *project*.

Given a set of files in a same directory, each file can be the unique file of a project -- I always have a tests/ directory where I host pet projects, or where I test the behaviour of the compiler. On the opposite, the files from a set of directories can be part of a same and very big project.

In the end, what really defines a project is a (leaf) "makefile" -- And why restrict ourselves to makefiles, what about scons, autotools, ant, (b)jam, aap? And BTW, Sun-Makefiles or GNU-Makefiles ?

Moreover, I don't see any point in having vim know the exact files in the current project. And even so, the well known [project.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69) already does the job. Personally I use a [local_vimrc plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc) (I'm maintaining one, and I've seen two others on SF). With this plugin, I just have to drop a _vimrc_local.vim file in a directory, and what is defined in it (:mappings, :functions, variables, :commands, :settings, ...) will apply to each file under the directory -- I work on a big project having a dozen of subcomponents, each component live in its own directory, has its own makefile (not even named Makefile, nor with a name of the directory)

### Regarding C++ code understanding

Every time we want to do something complex (refactorings like rename-function, rename-variable, generate-switch-from-current-variable-which-is-an-enum, ...), we need vim to have an understanding of C++. Most of the existing plugins rely on ctags. Unfortunately, ctags comprehension of C++ is quite limited -- I have already written a [few advanced things](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp), but I'm often stopped by the poor information provided by ctags. cscope is no better. Eventually, I think we will have to integrate an advanced tool like elsa/pork/ionk/deshydrata/....

NB: That's where, now, I concentrate most of my efforts.

### Regarding Doxygen

I don't known how difficult it is to jump to the doxygen definition associated to a current token. The first difficulty is to understand what the cursor is on (I guess omnicppcomplete has already done a lot of work in this direction). The second difficulty will be to understand how doxygen generate the page name for each symbol from the code.

Opening vim at the right line of code from a doxygen page should be simple with a greasemonkey plugin.

### Regarding the debugger

There is the [pyclewn project](http://pyclewn.wiki.sourceforge.net/) for those that run vim under linux, and with gdb as debugger. Unfortunately, it does not support other debuggers like dbx.

### Responses to other requirements:

> - When I run or debug my compiled program, I'd like the option of having a dialog pop up which asks me for the command line parameters. It should remember the last 20 or so parameters I used for the project. I do not want to have to edit the project properties for this.

My [BuildToolsWrapper plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper) has a `g:BTW_run_parameters` option (easily overridden with project/local_vimrc solutions). Adding a mapping to ask the arguments to use is really simple. (see :h inputdialog())

> - work with source control system

There already exist several plugins addressing this issue. This has nothing to do with C++, and it must not be addressed by a C++ suite.

Comment: Using several set up plugins to "simulate" a "project" is ok for me in case I am on the one big project for 2 and more years. Snippets, vimrc, and other things, they are files related. I will try to answer in the question what's define a project.

Answer (score 2):

Things I'd like in an IDE that the ones I use don't provide:

- When I run or debug  my compiled program, I'd like the option of having a dialog pop up which asks me for the command line parameters. It should remember the last 20 or so parameters I used for the project. I do *not* want to have to edit the project properties for this.
- A "Tools" menu that is configurable on a per-project basis
- Ability to rejig the keyboard mappings for *every* possible command.
- Ability to produce lists of project configurations in text form
- Intelligent floating (not docked) windows for debugger etc. that pop up only when I need them, stay on top and then disappear when no longer needed.
- Built-in code metrics analysis so I get a list of the most complex functions in the project and can click on them to jump to the code
- Built-in support for Doxygen or similar so I can click in a Doxygen document and go directly to code. Sjould also reverse navigate from code to Doxygen.

No doubt someone will now say Eclipse can do this or that, but it's too slow and bloated for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623605/c-vim-ide-things-youd-need-from-i/623630#623630):

- integration with gdb as in emacs.  I know of [clewn](http://clewn.sourceforge.net/), but I don't like that I have to restart vim to restart the debugger.  With clewn, vim is integrated into the debugger, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are developing on Windows, but if you are I suggest you check out [Viemu](http://www.viemu.com/).  It is a pretty good VIM extension for Visual Studio.  I really like Visual Studio as an IDE (although I still think VC6 is hard to beat), so a Vim extension for VS was perfect for me.  Features that I would prefer worked better in a Vim IDE are:

- The Macro Recording is a bit error prone, especially with indentation.  I find I can easily and often record macros in Vim while I am editing code (eg. taking an enum defn from a header and cranking out a corresponding switch statement), but found that Viemu is a bit flakey in that deptartment.
- The VIM code completion picks up words in the current buffer where Viemu hooks into the VS code completion stuff.  This means if I have just created a method name and I want to ctrl ] to auto complete, Vim will pick it up, but Viemu won't.

Comment: Viemu hasn't Vim's plugins power. Unix like systems only. Windows has Visual Studio.

Comment: Yep,  I saw your edits and realized what you were asking for :).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's just down to the necessities

- nice integration with ctags, so you can do jump to definition
- intelligent completion, that also give you the function prototype
- easy way to switch between code and headers
- interactive debugging with breaakpoints, but maybe
- maybe folding
- extra bonus points for refactoring tools like rename or extract method

I'd say stay away from defining projects - just treat the entire file branch as part of the "project" and let users have a settings file to override that default

99% of the difference in speed I see between IDE and vim users is code lookup and navigation.  You need to be able to grep your source tree for a phrase (or intelligently look for the right symbol using ctags), show all the hits, and switch to that file in like two or three keystrokes.

All the other crap like repository navigation or interactive debugging is nice, but there are other ways to solve those problems.  I'd say drop the interactive debugging even.  Just focus on what makes IDEs good editors - have a "big picture" view of your project, instead of single file.

In fact, are there any plugins for vim that already achieve this?