# Using vim for coding with in a big C++ project

Tags: c++, vim

Is there any plugin for VIM that I can use to index an C++ project code base?

I would apreciate functionalities like being capable of specifing a class and and may be a method and see what file/line the method/class is defined.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149558/recommended-vim-plugins-for-c-coding

Comment: Have you considered CScope/Ctags? You can also download eclipse-c++ which will have a regular editor with much better code browsing.

Comment: @jogojapan, this is not a duplicate of the question you've found. C and C++ are quite different languages -> ctag is bad, cscope can't be used.

Comment: Search for OmniCppComplete and clangcomplete

Comment: @LucHermitte I did not say it's a duplicate, but that it's related. I just wanted to provide a helpful link. And it is helpful, because some of the answers of the linked question talk about C++ plugins for vim, even though the title talks about C.

Comment: Looking at Luc's comment, I just realized somebody apparently misread my "Related" link above and voted to close the question as duplicate. That's not what I intended. (And it's not me who gave that vote.) I think this is a a useful question.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I've "reacted": somebody misread your comment.

Comment: I found the link posted by jogojapan indeed related and useful. However as noted, I want some useful links,comments and plugins for *C++* and *VIM*.

Comment: I gave eclipse-CDT a try but found it not so good as it is for Java. I'm considering now some alternatives like vim and emacs.

Comment: OK. If you are expecting more general answers (and not restricted to code navigation) you should update the text of your question.
I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Regarding code navigation (and completion)**,

I'd take a look at [clang_indexer](http://blog.wuwon.id.au/2011/10/vim-plugin-for-navigating-c-with.html) (and [clang_complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete)) -- 
ctag understanding of C++ code is quite bad, but universal-ctags has greatly improved the situation ; cscope understanding of C++ is non-existent.

**Regarding plugins for C++ coding**,

I have a suite for [C and C++ programming](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp). It is mainly oriented toward C++ programming, however a few, and unique features can be used in C as well:

- [context sensitive snippets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/doc/snippets.md) (they require other plugins I'm maintaining);
- a way to jump to a function definition from its declaration (or create it on the fly if it doesn't exists yet) (it used to requires the plugin alternate, which is a must have, however that I've [forked it](https://github.com/LucHermitte/alternate-lite) for my own needs) -> `:GOTOIMPL`;
- a little tool that lists functions with a declaration and no definition, or functions with a definition and no declaration (NB: I haven't used it against C static function yet) (it requires ctags).
- `:Override` that searches for overridable functions
- [`:DOX`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/doc/Doxygen.md) that analyses C++ function signature to generate the appropriate (customizable) doxygen comment (with \param, \throw, ...)
- a mapping to include the header file where the symbol under the cursor is defined* (which requires an up-to-date ctags base)
- and few other things

Otherwise, I also use:

- plugins like project/[local_vimrc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc) in order to have [project specific settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623605/c-vim-ide-things-youd-need-from-it/626698#626698) ;
- [searchInRuntime](https://github.com/LucHermitte/SearchInRuntime) to open/jump to files without the need to browse the directories of the current project ;
- a [refactoring plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-refactor) (that still lacks a few things ...) ;
- a wrapper around :make in order to do background compiling, and to filter &makeprg results (e.g. pathnames conversions between cygwin posix form and dos form ; application of STLfilt ; etc.) (-> [BuildToolWrapper](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper) which is stable, but still in an alpha stage) ;
- and a few other things which have already been mentioned (alternate, ctags, ...).

**Other Plugins.**

Other people use c.vim, other templating systems (snipmate & co), pyclewn (that I highly recommend for debugging (with gdb) from within vim), other bracket-surrounding-and-expansion systems, ...

PS: I've answered, slightly differently, a question on the same subject on [quora](https://www.quora.com/How-to-build-vim-editor-in-Linux-into-an-effective-C++-programming-IDE/answer/Luc-Hermitte).

Comment: Can I install both clang_indexer and clang_complete at the same time? former is a fork of the latter but it seems the project has not been updated for quite some time.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the answer either.
There are a lot of interesting stuff in clang_indexer that would make a lot of sense in clang_complete, which is maintained.

Comment: The link http://stackoverflow.com/a/152448/15934  is broken. Can you copy paste your answer?

Comment: @blueskin. It seems some people have decided that this question was off-topic. While I could certainly undelete it (I have sufficient right for it), I'm afraid it'll be lost fight, on SO. I'm afraid this question might follow the same path :( Any way I'll copy here what I've said in my other answer. Thanks.

Comment: @LucHermitte Agreed. Thanks

Comment: @LucHermitte Hi. I suppose you've done lots of work. Any video or animation to show all of that ? I think that will be more impressive.

Comment: @LewisChan There is no video no, sorry. There are a few screencasts here and there though: [Class snippets/wizards](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/doc/screencast-snippet-baseNV-class.gif),  [Background compilation w/ 2 active projects w/ different compilation modes](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/master/doc/screencast-BTW.gif) and [tag selection](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-tags/blob/master/doc/screencast-LHTags.gif)

Answer (score 3):

`cscope` is a nice tool for browsing. There is nice tutorial [here](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html).

`ctags` is another nice tool, I use it in my projects. Tutorial [here](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/). If you are in Ubuntu, you can install `ctags` by doing:

`apt-get install exuberant-ctags`

[gtags](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) is another tool.

Comment: +1 for ctags, I personally use it with `-R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q`.

Comment: I tried with cscope + c++ but the support is minimum. What these parameters --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q do?

Answer (score 2):

I use [taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) extensively.

> > > The "Tag List" plugin is a source code browser for the Vim editor. It provides an overview of the structure of source code files and allows you to efficiently browse through source code files in different programming languages. It is the top-rated and most-downloaded plugin for the Vim editor.